# Alfresco 4.2 CE with MS SQL server 2012

Tags: windows, sql-server-2012, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've been asked to use install alfresco 4.2 community edition with database MS SQL server 2012 for evaluation and I'm a newbie in using it. I'm having a hard time in doing configurations to make it work. I know MS SQL server 2012 is only supported in alfresco enterprise edition but I've read some forums and some of them made it work with sql server 2012 by tweaking some scripts but I don't have any idea what scripts or how to do it.

I just want to know if it is really possible to do it and if yes, could you please give me some detailed steps how to do it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're happy to pay Microsoft a large pile of cash for a MS SQL Server license, is there a reason why you're not willing to give Alfresco a much much smaller amount of money for an Alfresco Enterprise license?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no ready-to-install extension to add MS SQLServer support to Alfresco Community 4.2.x.
If you don't want to buy the Enterprise version then you'll have to add all necessary code like myBatis ORM files in your own.
It's not impossible but it's gonna be a hard task...

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server is a requirement, I recommend evaluating this trial using Alfresco Enterprise so that you're not modifying or introducing other issues that may present Alfresco negatively. (sorry I would have posted this as a comment, but I dont have enough rep-points).

Comment: I would love to do that but sad to say I'm also required to use the Community edition against SQL server 2012. I've searched some facts regarding this matter and found out that some of them managed to pull this off but they are using alfresco 3.4 against SQL server 2008.